# If $G$ is direct product of simple normal subgroups, then is every simple subgroup isomorphic to some factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G = N_1 \times \ldots \times N_k$ and $K \le G$ is a simple normal subgroup, then $K \cong N_j$ for some $i = 1,\ldots, k$. This could be seen by the Jordan-Hölder theorem, as the $N_i$ are the composition factors in some series, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622787/if-g-is-a-direct-product-of-simple-groups-then-is-every-simple-and-normal-sub).

But what if $K$ is not required to be normal? Does there exists a group with a simple subgroup $K$ which is not isomorphic to one of the factors $N_j$ in the direct product decomposition of $G$?

Comment: You could take $K$ to be any simple subgroup of a larger simple group. For example $K=A_5$, $G=A_6$ with $k=1$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! For arbitrary $k$ this also works, for example $A_6 \times A_6$ for $k = 2$.